# Is there any way of knowing the current value repeatedly when a valuechanged() signal is emitted by slider?

Tags: qt, qt4

while i am implementing

```
QObject::connect(mb, SIGNAL(valuechanged(int)),.............);
```

In this case how can i know what is the value at each time.I want this because at particular value i want to call a function.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The slot you connect to it will get the updated value each time the slot is fired, so what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Actually i want to call a slot at a particular value not all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide an intermediate slot that checks the value, and when it reaches your magic number, calls the function you actually need.

Comment: This is what the Help documents are for.